# SP_HELPTEXT sem formatação

Tags: sql, formatação

Quando uma Trigger é compilada pelo TOAD for SQL, usando o botão F9 e não o F5, ela é inserida no syscomments com uma formatação errada, como se fosse uma linha só, onde as quebras de linhas são desconsideradas. O problema é que ao usar o sp_helptext para trazer o texto do objeto, ele busca no syscomments e por consequência o resultado são linhas quebradas sem o menor sentido, e não consigo usar esse texto para recompilar o objeto.

Se acesso o SQL Management Studio e faço o seguinte procedimento na trigger que foi compilada com F9 no TOAD for SQL:

Para modificar um gatilho DML
Pesquisador de Objetos, conecte-se a uma instância do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados e expanda-a.
Tabelas e expanda a tabela que contém o gatilho que você quer modificar.
Gatilhos, clique com o botão direito no gatilho a ser modificado e clique em Modificar.
Executar.

Ele abre um editor de texto com a trigger formatada de maneira correta.

Minha dúvida é descobrir o que essa opção Modificar do SQL Manegement Studio executa para que consiga formatar o objeto corretamente. Pois preciso pegar o que a sp_helptext traz, formatar da forma correta, para conseguir criar esta trigger em outra tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a procedure abaixo.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_helptext2] (@ProcName NVARCHAR(256))
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @PROC_TABLE TABLE (X1  NVARCHAR(MAX))

      DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(MAX)
      DECLARE @Procedure NVARCHAR(MAX)
      DECLARE @ProcLines TABLE (PLID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Line NVARCHAR(MAX))

      SELECT @Procedure = 'SELECT DEFINITION FROM '+db_name()+'.SYS.SQL_MODULES WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+@ProcName+''')'

      insert into @PROC_TABLE (X1)
        exec  (@Procedure)

  SELECT @Proc=X1 from @PROC_TABLE

  WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc) > 0
  BEGIN
        INSERT @ProcLines
        SELECT LEFT(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)-1)
        SELECT @Proc = SUBSTRING(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)+2,LEN(@Proc))
  END
  --* inserts last line
  insert @ProcLines 
  select @Proc ;

  SELECT Line FROM @ProcLines ORDER BY PLID
END
```

Retirado de [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061642/sql-server-2012-sp-helptext-extra-lines-issue)

Comment: Jean, traz a trigger em uma linha só, pois no sys.sqlmodules ela já está assim, e na syscomments tbm, que é de onde a SP_HELPTEXT pega. Bom seria descobrir o que a maldita função Modificar do SQL Management faz por baixo dos panos que consegue trazer ela formatada corretamente.